# How to generate line chart with discrete value, not time serial, as x-axis

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Sorry for this silly question, but I am lost and hope any other expert can help me.
I need to draw a bar chart, but the x axis is NOT time series, it is discrete values.

```
var ndx = crossfilter( self.getStatus( contracts ));
var skuDim = ndx.dimension(  function(d){ 
              return d.sku;
});
var skuDimCount = skuDim.group().reduceCount();

var chartLineContractSku= dc.barChart("#chart-line-contract-sku");
                        chartLineContractSku
                        .width(500)
                        .height(200)
                        .dimension(skuDim)
                        .group(skuDimCount)

                        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain(skus))
                        .legend(dc.legend());
```

the skus is:
array of sku:
["PAR-ND-SRX1-SPCNPC", "SVC-ND-M10i", "SVC-CP-SRX3400", "SVC-ND-SRX3400", "SVC-ND-SRX3-IOC", "SVC-CP-SRX3-IOC", "SVC-CP-SRX3-NPC", "SVC-3-ND-SRX3-IOC", "SVC-CP-SRX3-SPC", "SVC-ND-SRX3-SPC"]
which is used to group dimension the input data.

But the output graph is always empty.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? And how to generate the barChart with discrete value? Also, another question is how to make the label vertical? as we have quite a lot skus.

Thanks

Comment: not sure and don't have time to verify but I think if you specify all the values in the domain you have to similarly specify all the values in the range, otherwise it wouldn't know how to map one to the other.

Comment: @Milimetric, that is I don't know how, if it is time, we can select min and max one, but for this case, it is discrete value, sku, how can we put a range?

Comment: It's usually a categorical or ordinal scale when it has string values. I think the clues are  `d3.scale.ordinal()` and `dc.units.ordinal`

Comment: Yep, the answer below is a better approach, using an ordinal scale.  If you're using a linear scale, you have to specify a range like `.range([1, 100])`or `.range([1,2,3,4,...])`.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon is correct in saying that you should use ordinal scale to get your desired result. Replace your d3.scale.linear code with

```
x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(skus))
```

Look at this as an example
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/